# own through stream does not pipe data

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm learning about node.js streams at the moment and therefore I'd like to write my own custom streaming module. Here is what I have at the moment:

index.js:

```
fs = require("fs")
var module = require("./module")
var ws = fs.createWriteStream("out.txt")

fs.createReadStream("in.txt")
  .pipe(module())
  .pipe(ws)
```

module.js:

```
var Stream = require('stream').Stream;

module.exports = function() {
  var stream = new Stream();

  this.writable = true;
  this.readable = true;

  stream.write = function(data) {
    console.log("write")
    stream.emit("data", data)
  }

  stream.end = function() {
    console.log("end")
    stream.emit("end")
  }

  stream.destroy = function() {
    console.log("destroy")
    stream.emit("close")
  }

  return stream;
}
```

in.txt:

```
text
text
text
text
text
text
text
text
text
text
```

The problem is that the `out.txt` is empty and the `stream.write` function is never called. Why is that so? If I comment out my middle pipe is all works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one bug in your code which can be easily fixed.

In `module.js` change:

```
this.writable = true;
this.readable = true;
```

to:

```
stream.writable = true;
stream.readable = true;
```

and it will work.

Also if you want to learn more about how to use streams, substack created a nice resource in form of a [stream handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook).

Comment: oh boy, I was blind! Thank you! I already read the handbook, thank's for the link anyway. I read different ressources while I was writing the module. Seems like I mixed several approaches.

Comment: I thought so, the this. ... works if you inherit from Stream and set things up inside the constructor function.